# Nginx redirect on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: nginx

I have 4 servers behind a router, firewall
    www.domain1.com
    mail.domain1.com
    www.domain2.com
Are setup in DNS by the service provider.
The 4 servers are named:
    esja.domain1.com  192.168.10.60
    mail.domain1.com  192.168.10.50
    processmaker.domain1.com  192.168.10.90
    hekla.domain2.com  192.168.10.70
    Router 192.168.10.1

Router port forwards everything to esja.domain1.com on port 80

Nginx on server esja.domain1.com  correctly forwards traffic to hekla.domain2.com using:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain1.com;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://www.domain1.com;
          }
       }
```

What I have been unable to do is to redirect traffic to processmaker.domain1.com

I am wondering if this is somehow possible without asking the service provider to set up another domain externally?

```
I was wondering if it is possible to use www.domain1.com/processmaker and somehow capture what is after the / and redirect based on that to processmaker.domain1.com?
```

The DNS behind the firewall correctly points processmaker to processmaker.domain1.com

Does anyone know how this would be done?

Comment: Can you explain another way. Tell, please, IP of each domain name (can change IP, just need to understand how many), IP of router, IP of physical server.

Comment: I have added the IP addresses of the servers and router. Also all the servers work correctly and can be accessed on the internal lan.  I am just trying to redirect when coming from the internet.

Comment: So, www.domain1.com has public IP pointed to your router, right? Router forward traffic to 192.168.10.60 (where is nginx running) and nginx proxy this traffic to 192.168.10.70. And now you want to proxy to 192.168.10.90 for some URI (for www.domain1.com/processmaker/), right?

Comment: Yes you are correct and nginx that does the redirect is running on esja.domain1.com 192.168.10.60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
   listen 192.168.10.60:80; # ip not required
   server_name www.domain1.com; # if this is single server block in config, all other domain come here too
   location /processmaker/ {
      proxy_pass http://processmaker.domain1.com/; # or ip can be used proxy_pass http://192.168.10.90/;
      # slash at the end of domain is important
      proxy_set_header Host $host; # not required if at processmaker we don't care about domain
   }

   location / { # all other requests come here
       proxy_pass http://hekla.domain2.com; # or http://192.168.10.70, here we don't need slash
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}
```

As you can see, config is simple. Each location can use own proxy_pass.

About slash at the end of proxy_pass domain you can read [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:

So, your processmaker.domain1.com will be requested URI `/`.

Also nginx will fix any HTTP redirects - URI will be correct. If processmaker.domain1.com server will redirect to `http://processmaker.domain1.com/test/` - nginx rewrite it back to `http://www.domain1.com/processmaker/test/`. More information you can find [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)

But also you can do it with domains only. If www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com point both to router, you can proxy one to hekla and one to processmaker

```
server {
   listen 192.168.10.60:80;
   server_name www.domain1.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://hekla.domain2.com;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}
server {
   listen 192.168.10.60:80;
   server_name www.domain2.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://processmaker.domain1.com;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}
```

But simplest way is to add processmaker.domain1.com to DNS with external router ip. In this case your server config will be

```
server {
   listen 192.168.10.60:80;
   server_name processmaker.domain1.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.10.90;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
First taking the time to understand and then sharing your expertise. It is very helpful and educational.
I have tried your solution and it redirects to the server processmaker.domain1.com.
However when on the internet the url becomes www.domain1.com/processmaker/.
But when you are on the internal network it becomes http://processmaker.domain1.com/.
On the internal network everything works fine.

Comment: But when on the internet images do not show and when you try to log in "page not found"
I am thinking that redirects will not work properly unless the DNS is the same on both internet and internal network.
So I am thinking that I may have to ask my service provider to declare processmaker.domain1.com in DNS?

Comment: You can try to add this to `hosts` file on nginx's server.

Comment: Also about images... If images use absolute path, yes, it will not work. Best way here to use second solution with separate domains.

Comment: edited about adding processmaker.domain1.com to DNS. Yes, it's the simplest way.

Comment: I have tried your second solution using mail.domain1.com and it works nicely. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

If DNS behind the firewall correctly points processmaker, why don't you create another entry for processmaker in Nginx?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "~^(?<sub>.+)*\.(?<domain>.*)$";
    proxy_pass http://$domain/$sub$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Probably because I do not fully understand the syntax. I will have to find some documentation and read some more. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but nginx says "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here

Comment: `proxy_pass` directive is allowed only in `location` blocks.

You should wrap this directive with `location` block.